# login to facebook from my java web application without going to facebook's login page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I want to log in to Facebook from my web application, but its redirecting me to Facebook's Login page.

Without going to Facebook's login page, can I pass a username and password and log in to Facebook from my application?

I'm using javascript's `fb.init()` and `fb.login()` methods.
Also I have used the facebook graph API.

Can anyone please help.

Comment: grammar + removed fluff

Comment: No, that is not possible. The whole purpose of OAuth is that some 3rd party provides authentication information about the user, and they can’t do that if you want to skip the step of asking them.